# MotionEvent ACTION UP Unable to detect long press

Tags: android, motionevent

I'm having some issues with MotionEvent. I want to show background changes when user **presses the button (but not released yet)**, so `OnClick` might not be able to help. I noticed `MotionEvent` is able to detect pressed and released.

As result I have implemented a simple `onTouch` event as shown below:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                // Make Background Changes

                Log.i("DOWN", String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()));
                sparseBooleanArray.put(getAdapterPosition(), true);
                notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());

            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                // Revert background to normal

                Log.i("UP", String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()));
                sparseBooleanArray.put(getAdapterPosition(), false);
                notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
            }
            return false;
        }
```

This means when I press -> Background becomes green

And when I release -> Reverts back to original (white).

It works well on **normal click**, but when try **long press**, `DOWN` is being called, but when release `UP` is not being called.

So I need to perform **normal click** again to get the background back to normal.

Is it the original design, and I need to utilize `OnLongClickedListener` and manually revert back to normal when **released**.

Thank You.

Comment: Consider using the gesture events, as they provide ways to separate click from long press. Have a look at this example: https://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/view/GestureDetector.java.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier to use a state list as the background of your item, using the pressed state. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#StateList

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@color/colorGreen" />
    <!-- This is the default state item, at the end of the list -->
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
           android:drawable="@color/colorWhite" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Hi, I have implemented state on the List Item and it works, now is it possible to change the TextView to white when clicked as background change, text became harder to read.

Comment: Glad I've being of help!